# fast-import crash Fatal: Invalid raw date

Tags: git, git-fast-import

I'm trying to do a ghp-import into a master branch but I keep getting IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument and a crash report:

`
      fast-import crash report:

```
  fast-import process: 9124

  parent process     : 1

  at Sat Jun 2 22:11:29 2018

 fatal: Invalid raw date "1527973889 GMT Daylight Time" in ident: osisieke 
 <christopherajulo@gmail.com> 1527973889 GMT Daylight Time

 Most Recent Commands Before Crash
 ---------------------------------
commit refs/heads/gh-pages
* committer osisieke <christopherajulo@gmail.com> 1527973889 GMT Daylight Time

Active Branch LRU
-----------------
active_branches = 0 cur, 5 max

pos  clock name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Inactive Branches
-----------------
refs/heads/gh-pages:
 status      : dirty
 tip commit  : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 old tree    : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 cur tree    : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 commit clock: 0
 last pack   : 


  Marks
  -----

 -------------------
 END OF CRASH REPORT
```

`
I think fast-import tries to parse
"osisieke " as a date which of course fails. I'm really confused as how to move forward. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your question a great deal by showing what you're actually running.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  (In particular, if I do a Google Search for "ghp-import", the top results include two *different* variations, and you're not showing the commands you use.)

In any case, the problem is that `1527973889 GMT Daylight Time` is not a valid date format.

The valid date formats are listed in [the `git fast-import` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html#_date_formats) as follows:

> The following date formats are supported. A frontend should select the format it will use for this import by passing the format name in the --date-format=<fmt> command-line option.
>
> `raw`
>
>   This is the Git native format and is
>   `<time> SP <offutc>`
>   . It is also fast-import's default format, if --date-format was not specified.
>   The time of the event is specified by `<time>` as the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (midnight, Jan 1, 1970, UTC) and is written as an ASCII decimal integer.
>
>   The local offset is specified by `<offutc>` as a positive or negative offset from UTC. For example EST (which is 5 hours behind UTC) would be expressed in `<tz>` by "-0500" while UTC is "+0000". The local offset does not affect `<time>`; it is used only as an advisement to help formatting routines display the timestamp.
>
>   If the local offset is not available in the source material, use "+0000", or the most common local offset. For example many organizations have a CVS repository which has only ever been accessed by users who are located in the same location and time zone. In this case a reasonable offset from UTC could be assumed.
>
>   Unlike the `rfc2822` format, this format is very strict. Any variation in formatting will cause fast-import to reject the value.
>
> `rfc2822`
>
>   This is the standard email format as described by RFC 2822.
>   An example value is “Tue Feb 6 11:22:18 2007 -0500”. The Git parser is accurate, but a little on the lenient side. It is the same parser used by *git am* when applying patches received from email.
>
>   [snip]
>
> `now`
>
>   Always use the current time and time zone. The literal now must always be supplied for <when>.
>   This is a toy format. [snip]

You do not show what options you passed to `git fast-import`, but the string `1527973889 GMT Daylight Time` begins with a rather promising value (`1527973889` represents a time during 2 June 2018, specifically `Sat Jun  2 21:11:29 UTC 2018`).  In other words, this starts out as a valid `raw` format.  However, the time zone offset, which *must* have the form shown above, is then given as "GMT Daylight Time", which not only fails to have that form, but is also nonsense: GMT does not *have* Daylight Saving Time.  (The UK goes to [BST, British Summer Time, in the summer](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html).)